# Show changes directly in the frontend or after the API request finished?

Tags: angular, frontend

So let´s say i have a row in a list represented by a table in the frontend. Now i want to remove that row. I have to send an API request to the backend to remove that row from the database. Should i visualize the changes on my client directly before sending the request so the client gets an instant feedback or should i wait until the API-request finished and apply the visual changes afterwards?

1) Apply changes on client immediatly:

```
list.remove(something); // The table won´t show the something item anymore
service.deleteSomething(something).subscribe();
```

Pro: Instant feedback, the user does not have to wait

Contra: If something goes wrong(it should not in this case), what the user sees on his client and whats actually inside the database might be different(until the next reload of the page). For example, item gets removed from the list on the client, but the API request afterwards actually fails, so the row was not removed from the database, but its removed in the view.

2) Apply changes on client after API-request finished:

```
service.deleteSomething(something).subscribe(something => list.remove(something));
```

Pro: That way, we make sure that what the client sees is exactly the same as what´s inside the database. If the request fails, the clients view won´t change.

Contra: The user has to wait a bit until he gets feedback. If he presses a delete button to delete the row for example, it will only get removed from the table he sees after the API request finished.

Which of the two ways is generally recommended for an use case in which the API request should usually not fail(unless a token expired etc.)?

Comment: In the 1st approach, data will be inconsistent in some cases and data consistency should be in top priority for any software application. I will suggest you go with the 2nd approach. Even though the user needs to wait, that will be very few milliseconds.

Comment: I think, second approach is more suitable in enterprise scenario. User should relies  on notification or some kind of message back from server. Most of the enterprise system is eventual consistency. I.e. azure, you update some think in portal it not immediately reflect on the system but eventually it will update and notify the user.